# Minimum SDK required for Wear Google Authentication

Tags: java, android, wear-os, google-signin

What is the current min SDK for the built-in Android Wear Google Sign-In? It is working for SDK 25 on an emulator, but not on SDK 23 (SonySmartWatch 3 & Emulator) so I'm guessing ≥ 25 is required.

[SDK-23] Getting following message: (although SHA-1 is correct)

```
D/GoogleSignInActivity: Activity request code: 8001
Google Sign-In failure: Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 12501, resolution=null}

D/GoogleSignInActivity: Google Sign-In failure: Status{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=null}
```

sign-in window opens and closes immediately without logging in

**Source(s):** In order to achieve a functioning Sign-In method I used these two guides/examples:

(1) [Authentication in Wear (guide)](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/auth-wear/)

(2) [Wear Standalone Google Sign-In (sample app)](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WearStandaloneGoogleSignIn/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Wear Google Sign-In Authentication issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50614074/android-studio-wear-google-sign-in-authentication-issue)